# Modify mongodb records before sending to api response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express

I'm using MongoDB as a database and express.js to build API.
I want to modify the response before sending it to the client.
here is my express.js code...

```
products.route("/:id")
.get((req, res) => {
    mdb.get().collection('products').find({_id:parseInt(req.params.id), status:1}).toArray()
    .then(response => res.status(200).json(response))
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
})
```

Like, I want to add some calculated filed to the response. suppose my response object from the database is this

```
response = {
    id: 1001,
    name: 'Apple',
    price: 120
}
```

Now, I want to add image field. so, my final response object will be

```
response = {
    id: 1001,
    name: 'Apple',
    price: 120,
    image: '/assets/images/'+id+'.jpg'
}
```

Please help me with this I'm very new in express.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your router handler, you would do something like this:

```
Products
    .findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params._id, status: 1 }, {
        $set: {
            images: '/assets/images/' + req.params._id + '.jpg'
        }
    },{
        new: true
    })
    .then(product => {
        if(!product) return res.status(404).json("Product not found");
        else return res.status(200).json(products);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(500).json(err);
    });
```

Use the `findOneAndUpdate` method from `mongodb` on your `Products` collection to update a document inside that collection.

`findOneAndUpdate` takes three objects as parameters:

- first one specifies the query condition
- second specifies the updated document

  - Here we are using the `$set` operator to add a `image` property to the existing document.
- third is an `options` object

  - set `new` to true to tell mongo to return the updated document instead of the original one, which is the default

Here is a reference to the docs, for more information: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/

EDIT: To modify the response only, you would do inside the `.then`:

```
.then(products => {
    const modifiedProducts = products.map(product => ({
        ...product,
        image: '/assets/images/' + product._id + '.jpg'
    }));

    return res.status(200).json(modifiedProducts);
})
```

Here we are creating a new object for each product that is being returned, by copying its original contents plus the new image property, then returning that `modifiedProducts` array to the client

Comment: Good solution for one return one record, But what when returning multiple rows?

Comment: @SurajBharti you could use `.updateMany()` to update multiple records and then use the same query condition in a `.find()` right afterwards to return the same records to the client,

Comment: I don't want to update my database, I just want to give modified data through API